# Widgets show up on Emulator but not real device

Tags: android

So I have created a widget, and if I install it on my emulator device (2.3.3) it runs just fine. However, when I run it on my nexus one (2.3.6) it won't show me the widget in the widget select dialog. Is there something I can refresh? Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

For me there was some issue with the Google Now launcher (Build from February 26, 2015) running on Android 5.0.1. After uninstalling "Google Now" from the Google Play Store and then reinstalling it (with the "Upgrade" button) my widget showed up in the list again.